# How do I find out which process opens a specific port on a specific IP address once in a while?

Tags: ip, firewall

Once every 5 minutes or so a process on my machine, with my main user id, tries to open a connection to an unknown IP address (no rDNS) at an unusual TCP port (>1k).  I can see this in the computer's IP firewall log because the connection is rejected every time:

```
[243678.820911] Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* IN= OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.1.33 DST=123.45.67.89 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=31984 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=31339 DPT=1234 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 UID=1234 GID=1234
```

Now, I want to find out **which process** it is (a few hundred are running) in order to stop it from trying, and to see whether this is something I should be concerned about.

How can I wait for, and detect, up to the process name, which process opens a connection to 123.45.67.89 at TCP port 3456 as user id 1234?

Comment: If the issue is regular ("every 5 minutes") then it may be a cron job, so looking at cron entries may be beneficial.  Otherwise you could look at auditd and create an auditctl entry to log TCP session activity; eg `auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S connect -k FLAG` will flag 64bit programs that call the `connect(2)` system call.  You'll need a similar line for 32bit programs if you have both on your system

Comment: Just to clarify: The firewall message is the PC's or your network's router? ... The IP address you listed in the question seems to belong to Samsung...  So, if it's the router's firewall, I would say this is probably a Smart TV or phone or something trying to auto-update...  you could use `watch -n15 lsof -a -i4@123.45.67.89:3456 -u 1234` ... which will check every 15 seconds.

Comment: @RubberStamp Yes, they are on my machine, not the router. So, some Linux software component or web page in any of the 5 open browsers.

Comment: @StephenHarris Thanks, I will look into the audit option, this may be just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a tight loop with netstat like this:

```
while :; do netstat -np | awk '$5 ~ ":3456"  {print}'; done
```

It's not very efficient, but it should be able to capture the pid and name of your calling process.

Comment: Thanks, this might work, albeit at the expense of 100% CPU because of the busy waiting...  still the `netstat` could miss the command - will try it out, though!